# How to edit the field while using ng-select?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-ngselect

- I have a dropdown field with values like 01.00, 02.00 etc.
- After selecting any value from the dropdown, I should be able to to
  edit it.

---

i.e If 02.00 from dropdown is selected, I can press backspace and change it to 02.30 by typing. Currently, I am unable to edit after selecting.

(I should be able to type/edit after selecting the value from the dropdown)

Time Dropdown Image -

[image: Time Dropdown Image]

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
       <label>{{'Pickup Time' | translate}}</label>
          <ng-select placeholder="Any Time" [virtualScroll]="true" formControlName="pickUpTime">
              <ng-option value="">Any Time</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="00:59">00:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="01:00">01:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="02:00">02:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="03:00">03:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="04:00">04:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="05:00">05:00</ng-option>
              <ng-option value="06:00">06:00</ng-option>
           </ng-select>
     </div>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://www.jonthornton.com/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, simlar to the basic example but time is given in the html file here. I need to edit the field only.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use native datalist https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward  I need to use ng-select, not datalist.

Comment: Hmmm, according to the `ng-select`'s API GitHub page, `[clearOnBackspace]` is on by default ([this is the option you're talking about](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)), however it's entirely possible that Angular Material recognizes `ng-select` as an alias for either `select` or `mat-select`, alternatively, it may be that some part of your infrastructure is messing with the `ng-select` component, so it shouldn't hurt to try using `[clearOnBackspace]="true"` inside of the `ng-select`. Let me know if this works, and if it does I'll set it up as an answer and elaborate, for others to see.

Comment: @fabc this is not working.

Comment: My mistake, `clearOnBackspace` clears the entire options, [reviewing further down on the GitHub manual](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#:~:text=editableSearchTerm), I've found the option `editableSearchTerm`. This option requires the following configuration: `[clearOnBackspace]="false" [editableSearchTerm]="true"` because `clearOnBackspace` will erase everything, `editableSearchTerm` lets you erase one character at a time. This should work (tested it with [the code snippets on the Github](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ui4zdb?file=src%2Fdata-source-options-example.component.html))

Comment: I am getting this error, **Can't bind to 'editableSearchTerm' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'**  Changed code: ` <ng-select placeholder="Any Time" [virtualScroll]="true" 
            [clearOnBackspace]="false"
            [editableSearchTerm]="true" formControlName="pickUpTime">`

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a notification about this... Apparently it's something that was an issue but is no longer an issue? Someone else mentioned this [bug](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1545) but Tadeuš Varnas (the person developing and maintaining ng-select) simply told them to use the latest version of ng-select, this is probably an issue that was not mentioned in the changelog, I guess.

Comment: @fabc Even I verified that post. Is there any fix for that?

Comment: @ClarkeGriffin None that I can tell, as my experience with ng-select has been on the code snippets I linked. It should work fine... The version used in the code snippet is `"@ng-select/ng-select": "6.1.0"`, so that might be where the issue lies. Perhaps using that specific version solves the problem? I also don't know your version of Angular, as it's meant for ">=11.0.0 <12.0.0", there could be issues there as well. Given that the latest version is 6.5.4, I'd consider downgrading to 6.1, it seems a lot more stable (given they're used for the examples), they've not updated the CL in 14 months.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `[editableSearchTerm]="true"`

Comment: thanks, it save me a lot of time.